# Разница между двумя колонками sqalalchemy

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Привет.
Имеется postgresql база. Имеются колонки типа datetime. Как силами sqlalchemy можно получить разницу между этими двумя колонками?

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться - почему именно `силами sqlalchemy`?

Comment: такие условия задачи использовать orm